# How to design a Azure Cosmos DB structure for a specific scenario to limit the number of collections created?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API.

I have a scenario in which I have various Locations which will contain modules. These modules will contain data. There will be Location-Module mapping which will be unique. To make it further clear I'll describe it using table structure below,

Locations -> Modules -> Data

currently the structure I am using is something like this,

We have a ModuleDataDB, in it we have collections (Names made unique by combination of Location and Module generated dynamically),

```
ModuleDataDB -> Location1-Module1 (collection)
             -> Location1-Module2 (collection)
             -> Location1-Module3 (collection)
             -> Location2-Module1 (collection)
             -> Location2-Module2 (collection)
             -> Location2-Module3 (collection)
             .
             .
```

Now the issue here is previously we were using Shared RUs (to reduce costs) for all the collection under this DB but now Azure has put the limit of 25 collections per DB if we are using shared RUs.

I am thinking of moving this structure to a more traditional approach i.e. to put all the modules from a single location inside a single collection i.e to say,

```
ModuleDataDB     -> Location1 (collection)                 
                 -> Location2 (collection)
                 -> Location3 (collection)
                 .
                 .
```

I need suggestions on how to make it cost effective as well as limit the number of collections I make. Is there any better way to do it? Also would it make sense to switch to a VM with MongoDB in it rather than Azure Cosmos ?

EDIT1 (Solution) : As suggest by @Cedric below, I am now using a single collection for the  all location module mapping and using a Synthetic partition key which will have several unique value like "Location-1_Module-1"

So it will have a structure like below,

```
ModuleDataDB     -> Client-1(collection) --> (Data) {
                                           LocationID : ""
                                           ModuleID : ""
                                           PartitionKey : <LocationID + ModuleID>
                                             .
                                             .
                                              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single collection can be a good approach. To ensure performance when your collection grows, you need to set the correct partition key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

Comment: Agree with this comment above. Cosmos DB is a horizontally partitioned data store. The most efficient way to scale is through partitions. This was you only need to dial up RU/s to scale out adding more physical partitions in the back end to support the increasing numbers of logical partitions (the values of the parition key path you choose in your documents). Using Collections as a partition strategy does not scale.

Comment: @CEDRICDERUE Thanks! This was very helpful. I have now modified the structure to just use a single collection and it will have a partition key to create logical partitions.